# flash as3 The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller when dragging a clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, drag

all I'm trying to do is set up dragging for my movie clips, but I keep getting this error:

```
The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
```

This is my code:

```
projectThumb.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onThumbPress );
projectThumb.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onThumbRelease );

function onThumbPress( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    setChildIndex( e.target as MovieClip, numChildren - 1 );
    e.target.startDrag();
}

function onThumbRelease( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    e.target.stopDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only function you're calling that would throw that error is `setChildIndex`. It's likely that `e.target as MovieClip` is returning `null`.

Make sure that you guarantee that `e.target` is always a valid `MovieClip` (remember that `as` will return `null` if the types don't match), or add a check for `null` in there.

Answer (score 0):

What Kai said...

just would like to add to it what is likely causing it.

If you click on the thumb (the actual thumb) it is a Bitmap object. so the target is not a MovieClip. Try running it in debug mode to make sure that this is the case. You can also add a trace `flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(e.target)` to see what ti is. If you are converting  a non related class (non MovieClip or MovieClip derived Class) then you'll get a null.

you could do an while statement to find the parent that is a projectThumb or just assume that it's the parent. Another way of doing it is adding transparent button that would cover the size of the projectThumb on top of everything so you know what's calling the click event listener

---

try...

```
projectThumb.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onThumbPress );
projectThumb.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onThumbRelease );

function onThumbPress( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    var target:MovieClip = findPT(e.target as DisplayObject) as MovieClip;
    if(target){
        setChildIndex(target, numChildren - 1 );
        target.startDrag();
    }
}

function onThumbRelease( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    var target:MovieClip = findPT(e.target as DisplayObject) as MovieClip;
    if(target){
        target.stopDrag();
    }
}

function findPT($mc:DisplayObject):DisplayObject{
    while (1){
        if ($mc is ProjectThumb){ // <- this is to check for the right class
             return $mc;
        }else if($mc.parent == null){
            return null
        }else{
            $mc = $mc.parent as DisplayObject;
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: I hear what you guys are saying here - but I still can't seem to resolve the issue. If I use the getQualifiedClassName, it returns "thumbClip" which is the name in the library of the movie clip that is dynamically being attached to the stage ( var projectThumb:thumbClip = new thumbClip();) - but even if I cast it as this, I can't get rid of the error. All I need to do is make sure whatever is being dragged is the highest element on the page.

Comment: added a function that will traverse through the parents until it finds the right parent class or null